# PHP Form Post + JS function

Tags: javascript, php, forms, function, post

I can't make work together my post code php and my js function.

I have a form to compile, in that form i have a phone number and i wanted to execute php and js functions.

This is my js function to check the phone number field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var link = <?php echo json_encode($pagamento_link); ?>;


$('#acquistato').click(function() {

    if (!phoneCheck(document.getElementById("privato_telefono"))) {
        $('#errore_tel').removeAttr("style");
        $('#errore_trovato').removeAttr("style");
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("done");
        window.location.href = link;
        return false;
    }

})
```

And this is my post form php:

```
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['privacy'])) {
    $ordine = KronosOrdine::initID($_SESSION['carrello']);

    $ordine->set('email', $_POST['privato_email'])->save();

    $ordine
        ->set('nome_fatt', $_POST['privato_nome'])
        ->set('cognome_fatt', $_POST['privato_cognome'])
        ->set('codice_fiscale', $_POST['privato_codice_fiscale'])
        ->set('nazione_fatt', $_POST['privato_stato'])
        ->set('provincia_fatt', $_POST['privato_provincia'])
        ->set('paese_fatt', $_POST['privato_citta'])
        ->set('cap_ordine_fatt', $_POST['privato_cap'])
        ->set('indirizzo_fatt', $_POST['privato_indirizzo'])
        ->save();

    if (isset($_POST['flag_azienda'])) {
        $ordine
            ->set('is_azienda', 1)
            ->set('ragioneSociale', $_POST['ragione_sociale'])
            ->set('partita_iva', $_POST['azienda_partita_iva'])
            ->set('sdi', $_POST['azienda_sdi'])
            ->save();
    } else {
        $ordine->set('is_azienda', 0)->save();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['form-condition-1'])) {
        $nome_sped       = $_POST['form-condition-2'];
        $cognome_sped    = $_POST['form-condition-3'];
        $nazione_sped    = $_POST['form-condition-5'];
        $provincia_sped  = $_POST['form-condition-6'];
        $paese_sped      = $_POST['form-condition-7'];
        $cap_ordine_sped = $_POST['form-condition-8'];
        $indirizzo_sped  = $_POST['form-condition-4'];

        $ordine->set('note', $_POST['form-condition-9'])->save();
    } else {
        $nome_sped       = $_POST['privato_nome'];
        $cognome_sped    = $_POST['privato_cognome'];
        $nazione_sped    = $_POST['privato_stato'];
        $provincia_sped  = $_POST['privato_provincia'];
        $paese_sped      = $_POST['privato_citta'];
        $cap_ordine_sped = $_POST['privato_cap'];
        $indirizzo_sped  = $_POST['privato_indirizzo'];
    }

    $ordine
        ->set('nome_sped', $nome_sped)
        ->set('cognome_sped', $cognome_sped)
        ->set('nazione_sped', $nazione_sped)
        ->set('provincia_sped', $provincia_sped)
        ->set('paese_sped', $paese_sped)
        ->set('cap_ordine_sped', $cap_ordine_sped)
        ->set('indirizzo_sped', $indirizzo_sped)
        ->save();

    if (isset($_SESSION['utente'])) {
        $utente = KronosUtente::initID($_SESSION['utente']);

        $utente
            ->set('nome', $_POST['privato_nome'])
            ->set('cognome', $_POST['privato_cognome'])
            ->set('telefono', $_POST['privato_telefono'])
            ->set('codiceFiscale', $_POST['privato_codice_fiscale'])
            ->set('stato', $_POST['privato_stato'])
            ->set('provincia', $_POST['privato_provincia'])
            ->set('comune', $_POST['privato_citta'])
            ->set('CAP', $_POST['privato_cap'])
            ->set('indirizzo', $_POST['privato_indirizzo'])
            ->save();

        if (isset($_POST['form-condition-1'])) {
            $utente
                ->set('stato_sped', $nazione_sped)
                ->set('provincia_sped', $provincia_sped)
                ->set('comune_sped', $paese_sped)
                ->set('CAP_sped', $cap_ordine_sped)
                ->set('indirizzo_sped', $indirizzo_sped)
                ->save();
        }

        if (isset($_POST['flag_azienda'])) {
            $utente
                ->set('is_azienda', 1)
                ->set('ragioneSociale', $_POST['ragione_sociale'])
                ->set('partitaIVA', $_POST['azienda_partita_iva'])
                ->set('sdi', $_POST['azienda_sdi'])
                ->save();
        } else {
            $utente
                ->set('is_azienda', 0)
                ->save();
        }
    }

    if ($_POST['metodo_pagamento'] == 'bonifico') {
        $pagamento_link = "/pagamento/bonifico";
    } else {
        $pagamento_link = "/pagamento/paypal";
    }
}
```

My problem is that when i submit my form, it only run js code and don't pass through this form post

Can you help me please? Thannks

Comment: I think this might be your problem, although its not completely clear from your description [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: I'm not sure if your problem is raised but you fail `json_encode` on a variable which is clearly not a json `$payment_link = "/payment/paypal" ;`, I can ask you if you send us any error from the js console